# How to prove $\mid \nu \mid \leq \mid \nu_r\mid+\mid \nu_i\mid$?

Tags: real-analysis

> For a complex measure $\nu$ and a positive measure $\lambda$ with $\nu<<\lambda$, how to prove that 
>   $$\mid \nu \mid \leq \mid \nu_r\mid+\mid \nu_i\mid$$
>   where $\nu_r$ is the real part of $\nu$ and $\nu_i$ is the imaginary part.

My idea:
$\mid \nu \mid(E) = \mid \nu_r+i\nu_i\mid(E)\leq \mid \nu_r\mid(E)+\mid i\nu_i\mid(E)$

Is it right?

Moreover, by R-N theorem, we have $d\nu=fd\lambda$ where $\nu<<\lambda$. So 
$d\nu=fd\lambda=(f_r+if_i)d\lambda$ which implies $d\nu_r=f_rd\lambda$ and $d\nu_i=f_id\lambda$. So $d\mid \nu \mid = \mid f\mid d\lambda\leq \mid f_r\mid d\lambda+\mid if_i\mid d\lambda$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&|\nu|(E)\\
&=\sup\left\{\sum|\nu(E_{n})|: (E_{n})~\text{a partition of}~E\right\}\\
&=\sup\left\{\sum|\nu_{r}(E_{n})+i\nu_{i}(E_{n})|:(E_{i})~\text{a partition of}~E\right\}\\
&\leq\sup\left\{\sum|\nu_{r}(E_{n})|+\sum|\nu_{i}(E_{n})|:(E_{i})~\text{a partition of}~E\right\}\\
&\leq\sup\left\{\sum|\nu_{r}(E_{n})|:(E_{i})~\text{a partition of}~E\right\}\\
&~~~~~~~~+\sup\left\{\sum|\nu_{i}(E_{n})|:(E_{i})~\text{a partition of}~E\right\}\\
&=|\nu_{r}|(E)+|\nu_{i}|(E).
\end{align*}

Comment: Is my method right? To use the R-N theorem.

Comment: Why all of a sudden there is such a $\lambda$?

Comment: I don't think it is correct because you are not told $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to anything.

Comment: If I assume that one.

Comment: That sounds weird to me.

Comment: I edited the question. Do you think it is right?

Comment: Okay, it seems no problem. But your question has nothing to do with Radon-Nikodym, that the $|\nu|\leq|\nu_{r}|+|\nu_{i}|$ need no assumption with absolute continuity.

Comment: Yes. But other textbooks do not denote the total variation of complex measures in this way.

Comment: I have a question about how to prove $d \nu_r=f_r d\lambda$?

Comment: Just compare the real and imaginary parts both sides.

Comment: Why $f_r d\lambda +if_i d\lambda=$ implies $f_r=0$ and $f_i=0$? You give me a couterexample https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416116/can-i-get-f-r-f-i-0

Comment: $f_{r}d\lambda+i f_{i}d\lambda=0$ and $f_{r}d\lambda(A)+i f_{i}d\lambda(A)=0$ for some $A$ are different.

Comment: you mean the first one is for any $A$?

Comment: Yes, so apparently the counterexample that I gave does not satisfy for any $A$ of course.