# Can I get $f_r=f_i=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

For a complex value function $f: X\to \mathbb{C}$ and write $f=f_r+if_i$. Can we get 
$$\int f d\mu=0  \text{   i.f.f  }  f_r=f_i=0 \text{  }\lambda-a.e.$$

Well, is it same with $f d\mu=0$ i.f.f $f_rd\mu=f_id\mu=0$ which is actually $f_r=f_i=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For $f(x)=x\chi_{[-1,1]}+ix\chi_{[-1,1]}$, then $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=0$ but the the real and imaginary parts of $f$ are not zero a.e.